# Как мне сделать обработчик по нажатию? onPress красного квадратика?

Tags: react-native

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{height:100, backgroundColor:'#263137'}}>
          <View style={{width: 20, height:20, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю что есть onPress, но он только для button работает. Как сделать банально нажатие на красный квадратик?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оберните свой view в компонент TouchableHighlight

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { }} >
    <View style={{width: 20, height:20, backgroundColor:'red'}}> </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```